# How to load a remote image, and then load it from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, snapchat

I'm trying to embed a snapcode on a page using their api: https://feelinsonice.appspot.com/web/deeplink/snapcode?username=USERNAME&size=200&type=PNG

The problem is that it limits requests so quickly that after just a few reloads, it returns a 429 error.

Is there a way to load it from the remote server on first load, and then from the user's cache on subsequent reloads? Ideally it would expire after a day or so and reload the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

You could control caching with a manifest:

e.g. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
also on w3schools etc.

Comment: This is a great resource, thanks for sharing – would something like this be good practice when building a plugin?

Comment: actually it might be tricky to achive this with usual plugin systems. but always it depends on what you want to achive. even more detailed control over caching you can have with servuce workers (JavaScript), e.g. https://dbwriteups.wordpress.com/?s=service+workers .